# google map and javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My current script is

```
       function markerOnClick(e) {
        var damId = e.target.damId;
        table.showTableFromDamId(damId);
        showMarkerFromDamId(damId);
    }

    function showMarkerFromDamId(damId) {
        if (damId in markers) {
            // zoom to dam and open popup
            markers[damId].openPopup();
            var zoom = 5;
            // find pixel location where the marker is
            var px = map.project(markers[damId].getLatLng());
            // substract y axis of the marker
            px.y -= px.y/100;
            // px.y -= px.y/250;
            map.setView(map.unproject(px), zoom, {
                pan: { animate: true },
                zoom: { animate: true }
            });
        }
    }
```

When I zoom in to click on a marker once I click that marker, then map zooms back out, how can I best work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because you are always passing in a zoom value of 5. 
Edit your code like:

```
 function showMarkerFromDamId(damId) {
    ...
        var zoom = map.getZoom();
    ...
    }
}
```